# Find records with leading zero in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a dataframe as follows

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Acct_no':['010122','002291','110082','000090'],
                    'Int_rate':[2, 3, 2, 2],
                    'US_GDP_Thousands':[50, 55, 65, 55]},
                   index = [21,2, 3, 20])
```

The above code results the following dataframe

```
   Acct_no  Int_rate  US_GDP_Thousands
21  010122         2                50
2   002291         3                55
3   110082         2                65
20  000090         2                55
```

How I can find all the column values where **Acct_no** starts with zero.

So, I would like to get the following result from the above dataframe. What code I need to run?

```
   Acct_no  Int_rate  US_GDP_Thousands
21  010122         2                50
2   002291         3                55
20  000090         2                55
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
df1[df1['Acct_no'].str[0] == '0']
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `startswith`

```
df1.loc[df1.Acct_no.str.startswith('0')]
Out[182]: 
   Acct_no  Int_rate  US_GDP_Thousands
21  010122         2                50
2   002291         3                55
20  000090         2                55
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
df1[df1.Acct_no.str.match(r'0.*')]
```